3D object rotation issue
I have something I don't understand during the rotation of a 3D object.
The idea is that I want to rotate my object around the X and Y axes. Initially, at the initial position of the object, I can rotate it around X and around Y normally. As soon as I rotate my object 90 degrees around X, I can no longer rotate it around Y (it rotates around Z instead)! I tried the same thing by first rotating it 90 degrees around Y, then I rotate it around X and I see that it rotates around x !
Is this a matter of relative axis? But if that's the case, it should be the same in the second case, right?
const char* vertexShaderSource = R"(
    #version 330 core
    layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
    layout (location = 1) in vec3 aNormal;
    layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;

    out vec3 FragPos;
    out vec3 Normal;
    out vec2 TexCoord;

    uniform mat4 model;
    uniform mat4 view;
    uniform mat4 projection;

    void main()
    {
        FragPos = vec3(model * vec4(aPos, 1.0));
        Normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(model))) * aNormal;
        TexCoord = aTexCoord;
        gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    }
)";

void OpenGlWidget::paintGL()
{ 
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mPushButton->texture);
    glBindVertexArray(mPushButton->vao);
    glm::mat4 model = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::radians(m_rotationAngleX), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(m_rotationAngleY), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(m_shaderProgram, "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, mPushButton->indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);      
}

void OpenGlWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) {
        int deltaX = event->x() - m_lastMousePos.x();
        int deltaY = event->y() - m_lastMousePos.y();
        m_lastMousePos = event->pos();

        m_rotationAngleX += deltaY * 0.5f;
        m_rotationAngleY += deltaX * 0.5f;

        update();
    }
}


Your results are consistent with the source code. "Is this a matter of relative axis?" Yes. "But if that's the case, it should be the same in the second case, right?" No, because the order matters. You may want to read this, this and/or this, and use quaternions to get the desired behavior.

@Yun I understand the point; I attempted using quaternions, but it resulted in the same issues because at some point, we do glm::quat totalRotation = quaternionY * quaternionX, and even here, the order is crucial, so I encounter the same problem as before.

Isn't this the exact same issue as in this question? Have you tried implementing Nicol Bolas' answer?
